# bgcolor vs background-color vs backgroundColor

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a "strobe light" for the heck of it in javascript and I found some code that would do it for me on the internet...but they used bgcolor and I felt that I should be proper but the code only works if I leave it bgcolor...so you know what I mean here's the original:

```
<html><head>
<title>Strobe</title>

<script>

function toggleBgColor()
{
  document.bgColor = document.bgColor == '#ffffff' ? '#000000' : '#ffffff';

  setTimeout('toggleBgColor()', 70); //in milliseconds
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad='toggleBgColor();'>
</body></html>
```

and Here's my changes:

```
<html><head>
<title>Strobe</title>

<script>

function toggleBgColor()
{
  document.body.style.background-color = document.body.style.background-color == '#ffffff' ? '#000000' : '#ffffff';

  setTimeout('toggleBgColor()', 70); //in milliseconds
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad='toggleBgColor();'>
</body></html>
```

I've also tried changing the document.body.style.background-color to document.body.style.background and document.body.style.backgroundColor ...None of them work...what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`document.body.style.background-color` is an invalid identifier *(well, technically it's a valid identifier [`document.body.style.background`], followed by an operator [`-`], followed by another valid identifier [`color`], but you know what I mean)*. Use `document.body.style.backgroundColor` instead. It *does* work, provided other things are correct. [Live example](http://jsbin.com/ixekal)

You've said you've tried that. I suspect the problem is that your code is failing elsewhere. For instance, you're comparing to `'#ffffff'`:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.body.style.backgroundColor == '#ffffff' ? '#000000' : '#ffffff';
//                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The browser may not (probably won't) report back to you in the same format you use to assign the color. That value will come back as `"white"` in some browsers, and as `rgb(255, 255, 255)` in others, etc. So the comparison will frequently fail, even when the background color *is* white. You'd have to handle that complexity, parsing the `rgb` and doing lookups on color names, etc. —or maintain a flag as in my example above.

---

**Off-topic**: Avoid passing strings into `setTimeout`; instead, use function references directly. In your case:

```
setTimeout(toggleBgColor, 70); //in milliseconds
```

Note no quotes, and no `()` (because they would *call* the function; we want to pass its reference in, not its return value).

If passing arguments (you're not there, but just for completeness), you can use a function to do that:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    doSomething("foo", "bar");
}, 70);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsure of the exact reasoning but css styles when referenced via JavaScript never have -'s in them.

If you checkout the W3 reference page you'll notice they provide the JavaScript syntax for the property in the "Definition and Usage" section :)
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Your next problems likely to be that many browsers (Chrome at least) don't internally store the background colour as a hex value, instead useing RGB's.

So your codes comparison would end up comparing "rgb(0, 0, 0)" to "#000000" and thus never returning true. A quick fix off my head would be just to use RGB values in your code.

Off the top of my head i'd imagine a fixed version of your code should look something like this:

```
function toggleBgColor()
{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = document.body.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 255, 255)" ? "rgb(0, 0, 0)" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
    setTimeout('toggleBgColor()', 70);
}
```

Anyways, hope that helps :)