# Javascript button click change background

Tags: javascript, html, css

The background color is not changing when I press the button. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var bgbutton = doucument.getElementById("bgchange");
bgbutton.onclick = function() {
  body.style.background-color = "green";
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FF9500;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<button id="bgchange"></button>
```

Comment: `body.style.backgroundColor = "green"`; Alternatively, you could use bracket-notation if you wish to use the hyphen (`body.style['background-color']`). Also, "doucument" is misspelled.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("body")` gives you a collection of nodes. The body element is at `[0]` index

Comment: could someone also tell me how to change the colour back on clicking it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a node list, so you need to pick an element from that with `[0]`:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

However, there is a specific property you can use instead:

```
var body = document.body;
```

Also you have a spelling mistake in the line that follows:

```
var bgbutton = doucument.getElementById("bgchange");
```

... should be `document`...

And, the style attribute names are in camelCase when written in JavaScript:

```
body.style.backgroundColor
```

... as opposed to how they are written in CSS (`background-color`).

Comment: also [`backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560541/bgcolor-vs-background-color-vs-backgroundcolor#answer-6560545)

Comment: you can just do `document.body`

Comment: You should in future keep an eye on the console. It gives you error messages that can be most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```js
body.style.background-color = "green";
```

It needs to be:

```js
body.style = "background-color:green"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a syntax error "doucument"

```
 var bgbutton = doucument.getElementById("bgchange");
```

Second

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
```

When you search dom elements by **Tag** or **ClassName**, in javascript you must specify what element index you want to modify in this case the first one.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

Above there's a shorthand how to make that, the document.getElementsByTagName return a HTMLCollection, containing the dom element as array to the variable body and you must to access this as a item in array with a especific index.

this works too:

```
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
```

And the body.style.background-color should be body.style.backgroundColor

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body").item(0);
    var bgbutton = document.getElementById("bgchange");
    bgbutton.onclick = function() {
    body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
```

```css
body {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FF9500;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
    <button id="bgchange"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to everything trincot has already mentioned, put something inside your button tag so it's easier to click.

```js
var bgbutton = document.getElementById("bgchange");
bgbutton.onclick = function() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FF9500;
}
```

```html
<button id="bgchange">Change color</button>
```